# Create new Tab facebook page

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create a tab for facebook page. Add in my html file this :

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'pagetab',
      redirect_uri: 'http://example.com'
    }, function(response){});
```

This opens the dialog, list the pages that are available and can add the tab. But the tab that is added is the default that believes in my facebook application. I need to know if there is a way to give a new tab name and content, set name, content etc etc.

Comment: _“But the tab that is added is the default that believes in my facebook application”_ – tell us more about this spiritual connection. (Or, preferably, clarify what you actually meant there.)

Comment: My apologies if I did not express well, basically what I wanted was to define a different value for each tab, but reading the documentation and watching examples I realized that this is not possible.

Comment: You responded in another post! @CBroe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140505/create-new-page-tabs-facebook?noredirect=1#comment59949547_36140505